# firebase more complex validation

Tags: firebase

I'm creating an angular app with firebase back end as an API.

People will be able to book appointments on a calendar but 2 persons CANNOT share the same hour slot. Furthermore, since appointments can start every half and hour, checking becomes a bit more complex.

Can I make firebase perform some more complex validation like that? It pretty much covers everything else I need and I'd hate to create something custom, only because of that feature!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something? If I understand well, you could achieve this just saving a value in Firebase (e.g. the appointment hour), then checking the same value if an user tries to save it too. Everything with a few lines of front-end code.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried so far? It's going to require a book chapter to describe all the possibilities without some more details about your use case.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet. Appointments are stored as JavaScript objects with start and finish date. Basically at the front end when someone tries to book something I make sure that the start or finish don't fall within another appointment. I'd like to have a similar check at the back end....

Comment: Jobsamuel I wouldn't want to keep the checks only at the front end only - that's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am correct, you said you don't want to do the checking client-side. Sounds good. Here's what I would do:

When storing the appointments, I would name them based on their times. Client-side code:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('https://example.firebaseio.com/');
dataRef.child('2014-6-9-0500').set('name'); // 5:00 6/9/2014 converted to a string
```

So the appointments will all be named based on their time, and their values will be equal to the name of the person being scheduled at that time. This will make it impossible for two people to be scheduled at the same time (because in Firebase, there cannot be two children with the same name).

In your security tab, check that the data doesn't already exist (to prevent over-writing existing appointments). Then, for the validate, you could check the appointment time and make sure it ends with either "00" or "30", and is 12 digits long. The rules would look something like this:

```
"rules": {
  ".read": true,

  "$time": {
    ".write": "!data.exists()",
    ".validate": "$time.endsWith('00') || $time.endsWith('30')"
  }
}
```

Although it's possible for a nonvalid time to be accepted (such as "0000-0-0-0030" or even "qt00"), a valid appointment which is submitted will not be scheduled at the same time as another appointment, and the appointments will be at times ending at ":00" or ":30" (half-hour intervals).

The only problem is if a person has an hour-long appointment starting at noon. You would have to schedule multiple appointments: one at 12:00, and another at 12:30. That could get a little annoying, but I don't know of any other way to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Timothy, I have thought of something similar :)

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, it is possible with Firebase. However, Firebase does not have the dynamic querying capabilities like Mongo does. I believe you have to take a pretty primitive approach to solving this issue by doing something like:

```
db.child('calendar').once('value', function(snapshot){
  var hours = snapshot.val();
  // for each hour
    // do validation here
})
```

Comment: Hello Sean, thanks for your answer! by reading the security API, I couldn't find 'db.' or '.once', am I missing something at the docs? 
Also I suppose you are proposing to put that under 'validate'?

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good, but it still keeps the validation on the cliend side, which I'd like to avoid..